# How to setup tSNE for TensorFlow.js?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am trying to run the simple tensorflow tfjs-tsne examples (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-tsne) in my own html/js project. The tensorflow core seems to be loaded correctly (e.g. the tf.randomUniform call works), but as soon as I call tsne (e.g. tsne.tsne(data)) I get this error in the browser console:

"Uncaught TypeError: n.ENV.findBackend is not a function" - when included with script tags, or:

"TypeError: _tensorflow_tfjs_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.ENV.findBackend is not a function" - when included via yarn

What am I doing wrong in setting up this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest release of tSNE is from [June 2018](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-tsne) and does currently not support the latest Tensorflow version (state: April 2019). There is already an opened [issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-tsne/issues/76) and a [statement from the author](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-tsne/issues/74#issuecomment-463445543) here.

You can downgrade your script to an older version of Tensorflow to use tSNE:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1"></script>
```

Comment: @mirjam Great, happy to help. You might want to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it helped you. :)